# Нужна Ваша помощь с рекуррентным соотношением

Tags: c++, функции, циклы

Здравствуйте, нужна помощь с написанием программы используя рекуррентные соотношения. Прикрепляю формулу вычисления функции и код, который я написал для этой функции и код всей программы. Прошу помочь исправить и дополнить код

[image: Формула]

Код функции

```
    double a = 1, b = x * x - 1;                                        // a = F1(x), b = F2(x)
    double  fn, fn3, fn2;
    for (int n = 3; n <= 3; n++)
     {                                                                 
      fn3 = ((2 * n + 1 / n * n)*fn - (n / (n + 1)*x*fn2));      // fn3 = Fn+1, fn2 = Fn-1, fn = Fn
       a = b;                                                // a = F1(x), b = F2(x)
       b = fn3;
     }
```

Код программы

```
       using namespace std;
 double f1(double x); //F3
double f2(double x); // G5
double f3(double x); // H9
double f4(double x); // F5
int main()

{

    double x, y, z, R;

    cout << "x = ";
    cin >> x;

    cout << "y = ";
    cin >> y;

    cout << "z = ";
    cin >> z;


    R = f1(x) - f2(f3(y)) + f4(z);
    cout <<"R = " << R << endl;
    system("pause");
}

double f1(double x ) // F3
 {
    double a = 1, b = x * x - 1;                                        // a = F1(x), b = F2(x)
    double  fn, fn3, fn2;
    for (int n = 3; n <= 3; n++)
    {                                                                 
        fn3 = ((2 * n + 1 / n * n)*fn - (n / (n + 1)*x*fn2));      // fn3 = Fn+1, fn2 = Fn-1, fn = Fn
            a = b;                                                // a = F1(x), b = F2(x)
            b = fn3;
    }


    double f;
    f = (((2 * 3 + 1) / 3 * 3)*f - (3.0 / 4.0)*x*f);
    return f;
 }

double f2(double x)
 {
    double f;
    f = 2 * (x*x)*f + (5.0 / 7.0)*f;
    return f;
 }

double f3(double x)
 {
    double f;
    f = 2*x*f-9*x*x*f;
    return f;
 }

double f4(double x)
 {
    double f;
    f = ((2 * 5 + 1) / 5 * 5)*f - (5.0 / 6.0)*x*f;
    return f;
 }
```

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить - что должна делать эта программа?

Comment: Просто перепишите `F(n, x) = A(n) * F(n-1, x) + B(n) * F(n-2, x)`. `F(2, x)`, `F(1,x)` у Вас есть.

Comment: не нужны функции, храните результаты просто в обьектах

Comment: стесняюсь комментировать, double f; неопределено а потом используется в выражении, / 5 * 5 делим потом умножаем на 5 без толку,

Comment: Сформулируйте четко само исходное задание, тогда будет понятнее, *как именно* вам помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на самом деле вам нужна одна фунция (если судить по формуле)

```
double F(double x, size_t n) {
    if (n == 1) return n;
    if (n == 2) return x * x - 1;
    double d1 = F(x, n - 1);
    double d2 = F(x, n - 2);
    return ((2 * n + 1) / n * n) * d1 - (n / (n + 1)) * x * d2;
}
```

да, чуть не забыл :  если  числа могут быть большие, то лучше определить тип для больших чисел и возвращать его, а не double (это уже другая задача...).

Comment: ((2 * n + 1) / ( n * n))
у тебя  F(xi, ni) просчитывается несколько раз для одних и тех же xi и ni, это оптимизируется сохраняя прочитанные значения в map,dict и т.п. я как раз занимаюсь деревом решений могу забацать но уже завтра)))

Comment: @ user184868, хорошо, но я  и не утверждал, что это лучшее  решение, а просто ответил на вопрос

Comment: я и не говорил что плохое, просто дополнил

Answer (score 0):

Вот, правда на Java но на C++ примерно то же самое:

```
public class FormulaDecider {

public static final double calcFull(double x, int in) {

    double []  backups = new double [in+1]; 

    backups[0] = x;
    backups[1] = x*x-1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= in; i++) {
        double n = (double) i;
        backups[i] = (2*n+1)/ n * backups[i-1]/ n - n / (n+1)*x* backups[i-2];

    }
    return backups[in];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double calc = calcFull(30,100);
    System.out.println("result: " + calc);

}


}
```

через рекурсивный вызова метода долго